# Multicore python as an alternative to spark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, multiprocessing, multicore

I have a python program which uses a lot of `pandas` and `sklearn` computing. It basically iterates over a dataframe and makes calculus.
The code uses the `map` function of the `multiprocessing` module. It also uses some `sklearn` models with `n_jobs = -1`.

It needs 1 TERA RAM and 100 cores to run. Sadly, the bigger machine I can launch in cloud providers is more about 16 cores and 100Go Ram.

Is there a **simple** way to adapt my python script to run it on a cluster of machine or something simimilar in order to deal with the computation?

I don't want to rewrite everything in Spark if I don't have to.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What kind of answer are you seeking ?

Comment: Please give more exact requirements (of the application not the hardware)!

Comment: @KlausD. I added some info about the program.

Comment: @eliasah I added some info about the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).

The project focuses into solving your problem.

> The execution units, called tasks, are executed concurrently on a
>   single or more worker servers...

Comment: Celery has no way to expose a data frame as spark does. IMHO, Celery is just a tool to distribute tasks to different workes, it is great, but it can hardly replace Spark. One has to do a lot of extra coding in order to distribute a data frame among the workers. 

http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/

Comment: The OP was specifically asking for simple alternatives to Spark as he/she wanted to avoid it. Please read carefully the question before downvoting answers just because you disagree.

Comment: Hi @noxdafox, I think that Spark, as it is, is more than just a tool to distribute tasks. It is powerful, among other things, because of the way it abstract data structures that do not fit on a single machine. I agree Celery is a simple way to distribute tasks. From OP text I can't read that he/she is not using that abstraction, in which case Celery is not a simple replacement. I got here looking for such type of alternatives, as such, I feel this answer does not fully address the question.

Comment: you are right. If OP is already using map Celery is a good replacement.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but for the people who stumble upon this question, you could also try [Dask](https://dask.org/).

[This page from the documentation](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/spark.html) describes how it compares to Spark, and the summary answers the question:

> Generally Dask is smaller and lighter weight than Spark. This means that it has fewer features and, instead, is used in conjunction with other libraries, particularly those in the numeric Python ecosystem. It couples with libraries like Pandas or Scikit-Learn to achieve high-level functionality.